# Do iOS development and distribution certificates share the same user id (UID)?

Tags: ios, certificate

I know this doesn't fit perfectly to StackOverflow, since it's not a programming question, but I hope if someone can answer this that it will help users which find themselves in a similar situation.

I'm talking about the certificates for iOS apps I can generate on this website https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action

[image]

If I create a development certificate the UID is **foo**, whereas it is **bar** when creating a production certificate. **bar** is also listed as "Team ID" in my account details.

Why does it matter? Well, I can't install the app I'm working on onto my device, since the provisioning profiles also contain **bar** in different places.

Can an iOS dev please open both a development and a production certificate and tell me if they use the same UID? If they do, then I know I'm on the right track.

The Apple support wasn't very helpful so far,

> everything looks good from our side

but if someone can confirm that something is wonky with my certificates, then I can try to explain to them.

Comment: When you download your Certificate, Then there is an option to choose UDID(There you see all the device add in your ID) Select Device on which you want to install your app......

Comment: UID and UDID are two different things. I'm talking about the user id of the certificate itself, not about any devices.

Comment: You create Production Certificate With bar UID.  and Development Certificate With foo UID . There are no problem you will make it and use it. That will Work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah I just checked(account type is company/organization ) they are different.Name in dev certificate is picked from apple id and for distribution company name.
Anyways this is not issue, if it would have,you must have got code signing error.

Comment: Thank you for checking this. That's all I was asking for :). Now I need to figure out what I could have done wrong. But that's another story.